# Could not load file or assembly 'Tools, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f7660c0f5438cda5' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#

Initially opened a project in Visual Studio 2012 and now when opening it in Visual Studio 2010 I am getting this error:

> Reference.svcmap: Could not load file or assembly 'Tools,
>   Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f7660c0f5438cda5' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Again opening it in 2012 also prompting for the same error and i have my project on version 3.5. I have no clue why it is asking for 4.5?

Comment: "Tools" is a very non-descriptive assembly name.  If you can't find it then I seriously doubt that we can find it for you.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this will help you. I had a similar error and it mentioned the Reference.svcmap, and the only service reference I had in my project was to the Bing translator service. I opened the configuration screen and noticed the red highlighted checkbox you can see in the screenshot below: 'Reuse types in referenced assemblies'. I didn't really know what the setting did, but I tried to uncheck it, hit OK and guess what... the project compiled and ran just fine!

After reading up some documentation on the setting, I actually got more confused. If you ask me, this error should have occurred on my Windows 7 + Visual Studio 2010 setup just aswell as on my Windows 8 + Visual Studio 2010 setup. Only the latter gave me the error though...

Update: Image disappeared. So open the configuration of the service (right click). The checkbox I am refering to has the label: "Reuse types in referenced assemblies"

Attached again the image. [image]

Comment: Sorry about that. Fixed it.

Comment: Thank you,
its resolved my issue. you save my couple of hours

Answer (score 1):

From the `Reference.svcmap`, this looks like it's a WCF reference. Maybe it needs regenerating under .NET 3.5?

Answer (score 0):

For me the error is because the project  use an external Library that it not referenced when I call a function.
This Library is developed with an other language (c++) in my case.
To fix that, I unloaded the project and opened the cspproj file, and checked this Library

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Lib\.......\Tools.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Lib\Lib2.dll" />
  </ItemGroup>
```